# let h be a harmonic function in a simply connected space $D$, prove that there exists an analytic $f=u+iv$ in $D$ s.t $u+v=h$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian

the question I'm struggling a bit with is: 
 
let h be a harmonic function in a simply connected space $D$, prove that there exists an analytic $f=u+iv$ in $D$ s.t $u+v=h$ 
 
I tried to solve by placing $h= u+iv$ into the equation given by h's harmonic attributes: 
 $\Delta h = h_{xx} + h_{yy} = 0$ 
 but couldn't continue to the proof without assuming f is analytic which kind of defeats the purpose if I understood the question correctly. 
Can I get a hint/tips ?

Comment: presumably $h$ real from your statement; note that since $if=iu-v$ then one gets $u+v=\Re (f-if)$ so let $g=h+ih_1$ holomorphic and then define $f=g/(1-i)$

Comment: wdym by R  - Re(f-if)? what's h_1?

Comment: Yes $\Re f$ is the usual way to denote the real part in Latex; $h_1$ is (a) harmonic conjugate of $h$ which exists (uniquely up to a additive real constant) on a simply connected domain, so $g=h+ih_1$ is holomorphic

Comment: I understand all the pieces but I don't understand how they complete the puzzle - why are we defining g and f with it as we do?, why is f = g/(1-i)? how is g being holomorphic help us prove f is?

Comment: $f$ is a constant times $g$ so is holomorphic, while the considerations in the first comment show that $h=u+v$ imply that $h$ is the real part of $(1-i)f$ so we find a holomorphic $g$ for which $h$ is the real part and get $f$ forced from it